# libgit2 pull file automatically if there are changes

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I plan to develop a program that will check if there are new commit in repositories located in server and pull it automatically if there is any new commit. Is it possible to do this using libgit2/git? Thanks

Comment: See the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347428/how-can-i-check-if-pull-is-needed-using-libgit2-in-c.

Comment: @JasonHaslam After getting the commit difference between remote and local repositories, can i just use pull or fetch to get the newest file? or there are other things i must pay attention for?thanks for your reply.

Comment: After your remote tracking branch has been updated, you can fast-forward (or merge) the local branch to the commit pointed at by the remote branch.