# LibGit2 Implementing 'git pull'

Tags: git, libgit2

I have choose the following algorythm of pull:

1. fetch()
2. get current head commit
3. get all not merged commits (realisation taken from here: [How can I check if pull is needed using libgit2 in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347428/how-can-i-check-if-pull-is-needed-using-libgit2-in-c))
4. get first not merged commit (it is newest) from step `3.`
5. merge commits. From LastFetchedCommit (step 4) into headCommit (step 2).

1-4 works perfectly

I have a problems with 5:

```
git_merge_commits(&rezPointer, repo.pointer , commitFrom.pointer, commitInto.pointer, &mrgOptions)
```

I'm trying to pull remote repo that have 2 additional commits relatively to local repo.

error:

> Error Domain=lib.git_index_write_tree failed: Failed to write tree. the index file is not backed up by an existing repository Code=-1 "Failed to write tree. the index file is not backed up by an existing repository" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to write tree. the index file is not backed up by an existing repository, NSLocalizedFailureReason=git_index_write_tree failed.}

do I did something wrong?

Comment: Do you have a problem with `git_merge_commits` or do you have a problem taking the index that it gave you and writing it to disk?

Answer (score 3):

That could be as described in [issue 2668](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2668#issuecomment-60689663)

> > If I call [`git_index_write_tree()`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/508361401fbb5d87118045eaeae3356a729131aa/src/index.c#L824), it fails with Failed to write tree. `The index file is not backed up by an existing repository`.
>
> That's what [`git_index_write_tree_to()`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/508361401fbb5d87118045eaeae3356a729131aa/src/index.c#L840) is for.
>
> But it's not about bare vs non-bare, it's about whether you asked the repository for an index or if you created one without any associations.

A bit like in [issue 5015](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/5015), where a reference to the index is explicitly set, and used (without error message):

```c
    git_repository *src, *dst;                                                                                         
    git_index *index;
    git_oid id;
    
    git_libgit2_init();                                                                                                
    
    err = git_repository_open(&src, "src");                                                                            
    err = git_repository_open(&dst, "dst");
    err = git_repository_index(&index, src);

    err = git_index_write_tree_to(&id, index, dst);
```

Comment: Will check answer in near few days. Sorry for delay and thank you for your help

Comment: @Andrew No problem. See you then.

Comment: I'm do not understand the answer. In my case I have only one repository. Local repo with fetched data from some remote repo. As I have only one repo I have tried get index from this repo and call git_index_write_tree_to for the same repo. And after I did steps 2-5 from my question and it is still fails with the same error. Did I misunderstand the answer?

Comment: @Andrew This answer was to highlight that calling `git_index_write_tree()` (called through your step 5 by `git_merge_commits`) might fail while `git_index_write_tree_to` would work.

Comment: I also have tried to to `fetch() -> git_index_write_tree_to()`. As result it's did nothing. By "did nothing" I mean that those 2 commits was not pulled.

Comment: @Andrew Strange: the fetch should have got them, even if the merge was not done (merge not done, means "not pulled")

Comment: https://prnt.sc/11cdmgi ; Maybe I did sth wrong? I've fetch info -> got index of my repo `(git_repository_index)` -> write it to the same repo with `git_index_write_tree_to()`. And no errors was thrown

Comment: @Andrew That part should be right. But writing to the index does not mean you will *see* the files. Just that they are part of the local repository history.

Comment: Please, check the comments on the following screenshot. As I understood this is a right way: https://prnt.sc/11cf801 . But as you see, error is the same. And error was thrown on the last step like earlier.